# initialization of property is not work in class but not in struct

Tags: class, model, macros

I have tried to change the struct into class to use the @Model and keep the same structure as in struct. I tried to initialize the property  as in  struct but it clash   in case of class for @Model usage.  I made a Question struct for question and Q  for answer branch.  Then I made a  userData variable using Question and Q. Then I initiate the userData.
When I used the strut I can init the variable and answer brand Q can be initiated but after I changed it into class answer branch does not hold the data. I make a view by using  the value assigned into answer branch and program crushed.

below is the example.

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct CharacterSheetApp: App {
    let modelContainer: ModelContainer
    
    init() {
        do {
            modelContainer = try ModelContainer(for: Question.self, Q.self)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not initialize ModelContainer")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
            .environment(ApplicationData())        }
        .modelContainer(modelContainer)
    }
}


import SwiftUI
import Observation
import SwiftData

@Model
class Question: Identifiable {
   @Attribute(.unique) var  id : String =     ""
    var year: String = ""
    var q: [Q] = []
   
    init( id: String, year: String,  q:[Q] ){
        self.id = id
        self.year = year
        self.q = q
       `
    }
}

@Model
class Q: Identifiable {
   
    var id = String()
    var q: String = ""
    init(id: String, q: String){
        self.id = id
        self.q = q
    }
  
}
```

```
@Observable class ApplicationData {
    var viewPath = NavigationPath()
      var userData: [Question]
   
    init() {
        userData =
        [
            Question(id: "230133", year: "2023" ,  q:  [ Q(id:"1", q: "1.적응장애"),  Q( id:"2", q: "2. 지적장애"),  Q(id:"3", q: "3.반응애착장애"), Q( id:"4",  q: "4.분리불안장애"), Q( id: "5", q: "5.사회의사소통장애")]),
            Question(id: "230136", year: "2023",  q: [ Q(id: "1", q: "1.제거장애"), Q( id:"2",  q: "2.폭식장애"), Q(id: "3", q: "3.신경성폭식증"), Q(id: "4", q: "4.제한형 신경성 식욕부진증"), Q(id: "5", q: "5.폭식/제거형 신경성 식욕부진증")])]
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(ApplicationData.self) private var appData
    var body: some View {
        Text(appData.userData[0].q[0].q) <- it clash
        QuestionView()
    }
}
```

I want to  initialize the appData based on Problem and Q but it does not work as I have change the struct into class and apply @Model macro. Let me know the method to initialize Q in Problem with values.